# Android: Sync CountDownTimer across multiple clients using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, countdowntimer

I am developing an app using Android & Firebase Realtime Database where users join a room, then when the host presses start game, all clients start the main game Activity (through a ValueEventListener on a "Started" child node in the room). The main game has a 60sec countdown where users make a sentence then at the end of the 60secs all sentences are collected and displayed.

I am having a hard time collecting all of the sentences at the end due to the 60sec timers being so off on different clients. I need a way to ensure all games end at the same time so the collection process is smooth and nothing gets missed.

I know that Firebase has both: `/.info/serverTimeOffset` and `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` but i'm struggling on how to use them to sync timers.

I have tried to use `System.currentTimeMillis() + serverTimeOffset` to estimate the server time and get all clients to count down to `endTime - (System.currenTimeMillis() + serverTimeOffset)` where `endTime` is a time written to the database by the host that all clients read but timers are still way off.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: how long is the timer offset among the clients?

Comment: I am about to implement something similar but I know the timers would be offset on different devices because of different variables. How were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

Instead of running a timer that updates every second on the server, simply store the start/stop times of the event and allow the clients to manage their own timers.

Not be done by -1 every second (as setInterval and other client-side tools are not very exact) but by comparing the current timestamp to the end, and determining the difference.